# Play framework Scala validation

Tags: java, scala, playframework, template-engine, play-helpers

I am  trying to implement password change.

I got the following two lines in scala. However even if I enter different passwords in both fields(`Password` & `Confirm Password`), it is saving the 1st field password WITHOUT validating.

I need it to get validated and display message if different passwords have been entered.

```
@helper.inputPassword(accountForm("Password"),'id -> "f_password", '_label -> "Password", 'placeholder -> "**********")
@helper.inputPassword(accountForm("Password"),'id -> "f_password", '_label -> "Confirm Password", 'placeholder -> "**********")
```

I have googled but can't seem to find the exact solution. Any help is much appreciated thanks.

**UPDATE**

I have got the following method in controllers in  NewPasswordController.java

```
public class NewPasswordController extends Controller {
    public static class NewPassword {
    @Required
    protected String newPassword = "";
    @Required
    protected String confirmPassword = "";

    public String getNewPassword() { return this.newPassword; }

    public void setNewPassword(String newPassword) { this.newPassword = newPassword; }

    public String getConfirmPassword() { return this.confirmPassword; }

    public void setConfirmPassword(String confirmPassword) { this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword; }

    public String validate() {
        if(!newPassword.equals(confirmPassword)) {
            return "Opps, it seems that you may have mis-typed the password, please try again.";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

But I wasn't sure how to use this in my SCALA.

I have tried like following

```
@helper.form(action = routes.NewPasswordController.NewPassword()) {
```

BUT this is not working, as my routes file doesn't have it. So, I am not sure how to mention NewPasswordController in routes (I mean is it get or set).

Comment: Why do you use the same `accountForm` field for `Pasword` and `Confirm password` inputs ?

Answer (score 1):

don't know about that way you are using is actually works or not,
but I think you need two inputs for passwords

```
@helper.inputPassword(accountForm("password"),'id -> "f_password", '_label -> "Password", 'placeholder -> "**********")
@helper.inputPassword(accountForm("confirmPassword"),'id -> "r_password", '_label -> "Confirm Password", 'placeholder -> "**********")
```

you need something like this in Your `accountForm`

```
public String confirm() {
    if (passwod!=confrimPassword) {
        return "password did not match";
    }
    return null;
}//offcourse you can convert into scala
```

Comment: Actually I have got this method in my controllers and when I tried it, its giving me an error. I will update the question. please go through.

Comment: @MissMintox i am waiting

Comment: I am so sorry about the delayed answer. I was away for whole week & didn't get to work on it. I have updated now. Please have a look.

Comment: Can you please have a look at this link here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140127/why-error-message-from-validate-method-is-not-displayed-in-the-template