# Why error message from validate() method is not displayed in the template?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

**Reason for Re-posting:** I have already posted this question  [**`HERE`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29090727/return-statement-not-getting-displayed-java-scala-play-framework)  , but I haven't got any answer but a comment which wasn't clear. So I am thinking to post it back again for some help.

SO,

I have a got a validation method for checking if both passwords (Password & Confirm password) have been matched or not.

This is my validate method:

```
public String validate() {
if (!this.password.equals(this.passwordConfirm)) {
    return "Passwords do not match";
}
return null;
}
```

And in my scala I have got as following.

```
 @if(accountForm.hasGlobalErrors) {
     <p class="error">
     @accountForm.globalError.message
     </p>
 }

 @if(flash.contains("success")) {
    <p class="success">
    @flash.get("success")
    </p>
 }

 @helper.inputPassword(accountForm("password"),'_label -> "Password",     'placeholder -> "**********")
 @helper.inputPassword(accountForm("passwordConfirm"),'_label -> "Confirm Password", 'placeholder -> "**********")
```

**QUESTION** : Everything is working as expected BUT when two different passwords have been entered in the fields, it is NOT displaying the error message returned from `validate()` method. I have no idea why. Following is my CSS for error.

```
p.error{
   border-style: outset;
   border-radius: 5px; 
   color: red;
   font-weight: bold;
   background-color: white;
   padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

**UPDATE** : I got to know from a comment that, I HAVE BEEN MISSING some action but I didn't quite get it. I am new to this stuff, any clear help is much appreciated.

**UPDATE** : I have tried writing the return statement in `validate()` method as below:

```
return Context.current().flash().put("error", "Passwords do not match");
```

This neither worked! The problem with this is that, it is displaying the return statement but after saving the page which shouldn't be happening!

Comment: You know that return statements don't display things, right? That's just not what they do. (That's like asking why `int i = 5;` doesn't display 5)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return statement not getting displayed - Java, Scala, Play Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29090727/return-statement-not-getting-displayed-java-scala-play-framework)

Comment: @immibis But this is a flash error thing in web developing!

Comment: @davide I have specified it in the question! Please check!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't realise the framework called `validate`. (If you were writing your own code from scratch then of course nothing would get displayed unless you displayed it; but in this case, whatever your validate method returns, the framework uses that as an error message)

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire/258208#258208

Comment: TBH i needed several minutes to realize what are you asking about ;) Which version of Play exactly? Add proper tags. And show us your action (that means method like `public static Result update() ` )

Comment: Sorry I have added the tag now. And I do not have any method like that? :/ I am confused can you please elaborate?

Comment: I have edited with another UPDATE, please have a go through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment (must have 50 reputation to do), so I'll ask the question here. What's the content of your controller action that binds the form from the request?

You must have something like:

```
public final Result submit() {
    Result result = null;

    Form<Something> boundForm = Form.form(Something.class).bindFromRequest();
    if (boundForm.hasErrors()) {
        result = badRequest(sometemplate.render(boundForm));
    } else {
        potentiallyDoSomethingWith(boundForm.get());
        result = redirect(route.Application.somewhere());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Don't you?

Comment: Actually I have this in my controllers which is linked to OTHER password change option (Forgot password request) but not THIS (which I specified in the question) change password thing. What should I be doing now? :/

Comment: You should push your code on GitHub and post the link here.

Comment: Actually I found another way to solve this! Thank you! Your answer was helpful in finding a way to fix my problem! It made me think!